# Strategy for migrating older files

Tags: duplicity

I want to have a rock solid tool to move older files to a slower disk - a migration instead of a backup.

I was thinking Duplicity would be a good candidate, though I would need a reliable way of deleting the source files once they are backed up and making sure Duplicity does not propagate this deletion to the backup.

Is this the right approach? How would you implement this strategy.

Comment: Looked at ZFS for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing duplicity does what you expect. Duplicity can do incremental (compressed,encrypted) backups and store those in some file/object storage.

But it does not touch the source files. It does not move those. And it is not meant, to move files someplace else and let you access those directly. To get files out of backup, you need to use duplicity again (or manualy gpg and rdiffdir).